# How to plot graph between x axis as date time and y axis as value

Tags: java, android, graph, mpandroidchart

I am having data of sensor value and datetime format which was in format(Year-month-dateThour:min:secZ) for example "2019-05-29T12:48:18Z"value.I want to print the values taken from sensor data and plot the graph in xaxis as datetime and yaxis as value. I know how to plot in yaxis value and how to add xaxis lable also please help

This was my mobilefragment class where it starts executing background process so that data has been taken from server and plot it in mobile fragmentclass(where linechart is in mobilefragmentactivity )

```
public class mobilefragment extends Fragment {
    public static TextView data;
    public static LineChart mchart;
    public static Button click;
    List<Entry> x;
    ArrayList<String> y;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mchart=view.findViewById(R.id.linechart);
        click=view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fetchdata process=new fetchdata();
                process.execute();

            }
        });
        //data=view.findViewById(R.id.fetcheddata);
    }
}
```

This is background process class and when data is taken from server after onpostexecution the data is plotted in mobilefragment activity and also i want datetime format in xaxis where it is stored in List named 'y'

```
public class fetchdata extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    String data="";
    String dataparsed="";
    String singleparsed="";
    List<Entry> x;
    List<String> y;
    boolean flag=false;

    /*Context ctx;

    fetchdata(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }*/
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        x = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        y = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            URL url=new URL("https://io.adafruit.com/api/v2/Yarev/feeds/pir-sensor/data");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line="";
            while (line!=null)
            {
                line=bufferedReader.readLine();
                data=data+line;
            }
            JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(data);
            for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject JO= (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                singleparsed="Value:"+JO.get("value")+"\n"+
                        "Feed key:"+JO.get("feed_key")+"\n"+
                        "Created:"+JO.get("created_at")+"\n";
                int value=JO.getInt("value");
                float v1=value;
                String time=JO.getString("created_at");
                x.add(new Entry(i,v1));
                y.add(time);  //time string
                dataparsed=dataparsed+singleparsed;
            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //mobilefragment.data.setText(this.dataparsed);

        mobilefragment.mchart.setDragEnabled(true);
        mobilefragment.mchart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        mobilefragment.mchart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        mobilefragment.mchart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        mobilefragment.mchart.setPinchZoom(false);
        XAxis xl = mobilefragment.mchart.getXAxis();
        xl.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
        YAxis leftAxis = mobilefragment.mchart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setInverted(false);
        YAxis rightAxis = mobilefragment.mchart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
        Legend l = mobilefragment.mchart.getLegend();
        l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
        LineDataSet set1=new LineDataSet(x,"Data set 1");
        set1.setFillAlpha(110);
        set1.setValueTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        List<ILineDataSet> datasets= new ArrayList<>();
        datasets.add(set1);
        LineData data=new LineData(datasets);
        mobilefragment.mchart.setData(data);
        mobilefragment.mchart.invalidate();
        mobilefragment.click.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, Main2Activity.class));


    }
    public List<Entry> getList() {
        return x;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView

Using this u can achieve your requirements

Comment: can you please elaborate and i am using philjay graph

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the list that will set data in the graph. If yes, then this code will help you. Let me know if you need anything...

```
ArrayList<ILineDataSet>  lines = getLineDataSetAsPerGraphType(bookingLineList);


    XAxis x = lineChart.getXAxis();
    x.setDrawGridLines(false);
    x.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    x.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_aeaeae));
    x.setTextSize(9);
    x.setLabelRotationAngle(-30f);
    x.setLabelsToSkip(0);

    YAxis yLabels1 = lineChart.getAxisRight();
    yLabels1.setEnabled(false);
    yLabels1.setDrawGridLines(false);

    String[] xAxis = new String[bookingLineList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < bookingLineList.size(); i++) {
        xAxis[i] = DateUtils.changeDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", "MMM dd", bookingLineList.get(i).getBooking_date());
    }

    lineChart.setData(new LineData(xAxis, lines));
    lineChart.setDragEnabled(true);

    lineChart.animateX(1000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuart);

    // Scroll
    lineChart.canScrollHorizontally(5); // Scroll = true
    lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10f); // Min Gap between two values
    lineChart.moveViewToX(0f); // Show from
```